# Dxf2gcode using python

Tags: python

I want to process .dxf file, detect color, shapes and get coordinates of each shapes. How can I do that?

Comment: Going through raster format (PNG) for generating gcode is a terrible idea. What sort of gcode are you looking for (for what machine)?

Comment: i want to process the file add points on shapes with specific distance and also detect colors. And then note those coordinates. Done this by extracting shapes from .dxf to .png but resolutions was changed. so now i have to get gcode file and then process that. i am using windows.

Comment: Why do you "have to get a gcode file"? It sounds like you should process the DXF file instead.

Comment: yes, absolutely but not found anything in python to directly detect shapes and colors and then add points on that.

Comment: Okay. Could you please rephrase your question in a way that tells you what your actual end goal is? If I understand you correctly, you don't necessarily need any gcode at all.

Comment: Have you looked at https://pypi.org/project/ezdxf/ ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.